# Compare stored epoch Date to current Date in php

Tags: php, date, epoch

I am making a php script which I will schedule to run every day at 9 AM.

I need to loop through all stored details in a cards table in my DB. Within each row I have an expirationDate column and i need to check if that value is within 3 months of the current date and if so send out an email to remind the user that their card will expire soon. They also want a second reminder sent if the expirationDate is within a month.

The bit I'm having trouble with is the comparison logic for checking if the expiration date is within 3 months of the current date. Code below:

```
...
if ($Cards = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($Cards))
            {    
                $email = $row['email'];
                $name = $row['Name'];
                $expDate = $row['expDate'];
                $reminderSent = $row['reminderSent'];
                $timeDiff = (intVal(time()) - intVal($expDate));
                echo "curDate is ". time() . " and expDate is ".$expDate. ". Difference is ".(intval(time()) - intVal($expDate));
                echo "<br>";

                //if ($timeDiff within3months){
                //    if ($reminderSent == 0) {
                //          //php code to send email
                //    }
                //    else if ($reminderSent == 1 && $timeDiff within1month){
                //          //php code to send email
                //    }     
                //}

            }
        }
...
```

I had a thought, I could maybe find the epoch value for 3 months and add that to my expiration date val and check if the curDate is greater than this. Would something like that work?

```
E.G: $expDate + 5097600 > intVal(time())
```

Any advice appreciated on if there is a better approach to solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the unix timestamp for the date three months ago with `strtotime('-3 months');` and can compare it to the timestamp you have in `$row['expDate']`.

Another solution would be to compare it in SQL:

```
DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(expDate), DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
```

will give you a positive value if `expDate` is within that range and a negative value else.

Comment: row['expDate'] is already an epoch so I would not need to use strtotime there right?

Comment: Oh okay, then I modify my answer. You know that these date calculations can be done in MySQL as well very efficiently with `[DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)`?

Comment: something like SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(expDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    cards
WHERE   expDate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()

Comment: Yep, but I think you will have to use `DATE_SUB()`. Keep an eye on the fact that three months are not 90 days, especially in business and legal context.

Comment: thank you for the help. I tried select DATE_DIFF(expDate, DATE_SUB(CURDATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) as diffdate, ID, Name, WorkerID, pic, expDate
FROM cards where diffdate > 0
but that's telling me datediff is not a table in my db

Comment: datediff or date_diff? I missed the underscore in my misformatted comment, but look at the answer.

Comment: I think I'm mixing up your approach re. php and sql. Your answer saying to compare in sql is actually using php functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88012/discussion-between-user2363025-and-syck).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to `intVal()` the `time()` function. But if you want to switch your best bet is [DateTime diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime($expDate);
$diff = $then->diff($now);
echo 'Difference is ' . $diff->format('%a days');
```